# Create calendar programmatically in swift/accessing with built-in iOS calendar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, eventkit

I'm trying to create a custom calendar within my app and found a tutorial on building a custom calendar (https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) which I followed in a new project and it worked. however, the tutorial uses storyboard and my app does not. I have, therefore, attempted to migrate the storyboard UI setup into code, using subviews, but was unsuccessful.

The aim of the feature is to store business meetings in the calendar, and I am willing to forego the custom calendar feature and access the iOS calendar, but I am unsure how to do this.

The error I get when I try to run this is Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at view.addSubview(calendarView)

The app uses a TabBarController to navigate, Organiser is one of my tabs.

Any help on either making the custom calendar work, or what code I could use to access the iOS calendar would be much appreciated.

code below.

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar
import EventKit
class Organiser: UIViewController {

var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!
var year: UILabel!
var month: UILabel!

let outsideMonthColour = UIColor.white
let monthColour = UIColor.black
let selectedMonthColour = UIColor.red
let currentDateSelectedColour = UIColor.blue


let formatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(calendarView)
    view.addSubview(year)
    view.addSubview(month)


    calendarView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
    calendarView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive=true
    calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    calendarView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: -30)

    month.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: calendarView.topAnchor, constant: 25)
    month.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: calendarView.leftAnchor, constant: 0)


    year.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: month.topAnchor, constant: 25)
    year.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: month.leftAnchor, constant: 25)

    calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    month.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    year.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


//setup calendar cells
func setupCalendarView(){
    calendarView.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    calendarView.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    calendarView.visibleDates { visibleDates in
        self.setupViewsOfCalendar(from: visibleDates)
    }
}

//setup selected cell text colour function
func handleCellTextColour(view: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState){
    guard let validCell = view as? CustomCell else { return }

    if cellState.isSelected {
        validCell.dateLabel?.textColor = currentDateSelectedColour
    } else {
        if cellState.dateBelongsTo == .thisMonth {
            validCell.dateLabel?.textColor = monthColour
        } else {
            validCell.dateLabel?.textColor = outsideMonthColour
        }
    }

}

//setup selected cell highlight function
func handleCellSelected(view: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState){
    guard let validCell = view as? CustomCell else { return }

    if cellState.isSelected {
        validCell.selectedView?.isHidden = false
    } else {
        validCell.selectedView?.isHidden = true
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}


extension Organiser: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource{
func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy mm dd"
    formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
    formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

    let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017 01 01")
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2018 12 31")

    let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate!, endDate: endDate!)
    return parameters
}

}


extension Organiser: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate{

func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplay cell: JTAppleCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCustomCell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    myCustomCell.dateLabel?.text = cellState.text

    handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    handleCellTextColour(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    return ()
}

func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
    let myCustomCell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    self.calendar(calendar, willDisplay: myCustomCell, forItemAt: date, cellState: cellState, indexPath: indexPath)
    myCustomCell.dateLabel?.text = cellState.text
    return myCustomCell
}
//function for handling interface changes when cell selected
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    handleCellTextColour(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
}
//function for handling interface changes when cell deselected selected
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didDeselectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    handleCellSelected(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
    handleCellTextColour(view: cell, cellState: cellState)
}
//function so that month and year show when calendar loads
func setupViewsOfCalendar(from visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo){
    let date = visibleDates.monthDates.first!.date

    self.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
    self.year.text = self.formatter.string(from: date)

    self.formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    self.month.text = self.formatter.string(from: date)
}

//function to change month when calendar scrolled
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didScrollToDateSegmentWith visibleDates: DateSegmentInfo) {
    let date = visibleDates.monthDates.first!.date

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
    year.text = formatter.string(from: date)

    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"
    month.text = formatter.string(from: date)
}

}
```

Comment: In your xib, did you connect the FTAppleCalendarView and the UILabels? If you have connected then the crash wont happen.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I'm trying to just use code to build my app - not storyboard or xib files

Answer (score 1):

The crash you are getting is because you are not initialising the JTAppleCalendarView so when you are trying to add it as a subview it is nil. Compiler does not complain because you are force unwrapping it in the declaration.

Replace

```
var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!
```

With

```
let calendarView = JTAppleCalendarView()
```

Note that you will get crashes for the same reason in the next two lines as well when you are trying to add the year and month labels as subviews.

You can replace their declarations with with:

```
let year = UILabel()
let month = UILabel()
```

Comment: thanks! that makes sense, and I can now build and run the app with any errors, but the view controller 'Organiser' is still blank when my app runs. Is there anything else I'm missing to make the calendar visible?

Comment: I have edited my constraints to include translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints and add calendarView constraints, but it still does not show

Comment: You have issues with the constraints code. .isActive=true is only set on the top two. The multiplier set to -30 means the width is calculated as view.width * -30. So if the view width is 100pt the calendar width will be -3000. You also don't have width/height constraints for the month and year labels

Answer (score 0):

You are force unwrapping an instance of JTAppleCalendar by using "!". So while force unwrapping if the value is nil, the app will crash. To avoid the same you need to follow the below steps.

**Step 1**: You can add a UIView from Object Library in to the xib or storyboard.

**Step 2**: Then you need to set the JTAppleCalenderView in Identity Inspector as given in the below image.[image]

Then you can use the same code as you have used and it should not crash.

**Note:** You need to add the same with UILabel also to avoid crash from UILabel.